# Javascript assign value to HTML field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to save an HTML field (for later use in a form) from a JS script.

This is the code:

Form

```
<form class="new_client" id="new_client" action="/clients" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-input" type="hidden" name="client[city]" id="client_city">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-input" type="hidden" name="client[address]" id="client_address">
      </div>
      <div id="locationField">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn button-general ">Save</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
function configureGeoAutocomplete(context) {
  if( context === undefined ) {
    context = $('body');
  }
  var element = context.find('.autocomplete')
  //It doesn't really matter what this line does, it's from Google Places API
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      element[0], {types: ['geocode']});

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress)
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var client_address = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
  document.getElementById("client_address").value = client_address;
}
```

The javascript is queried when loading the modal in which the form is

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('div.modal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e) {
    configureGeoAutocomplete(context);
  }
}
```

I wanna save that client_address to the text field so when the form is submitted I can have that information.

Comment: Which portion of `js` does not return expected results ?

Comment: I have little knowledge of js but in fillInAddress() function, the second line should modify the HTML field of id client_address, or at least thats what i want to do there.

Comment: Is the context in the on('loaded.bs.modal') variable initialized?

Comment: How do I check that? I'm very new to js and JQuery and don't know many things yet.

Comment: Tried passing `$("body")` to `configureGeoAutocomplete` , removing `if` that checks if `context` is `undefined` ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that is for but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for some reason, if I searched the element by ID it was not saving the information on the field. If I istead search by class:

```
function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  $(".client-address").val(place.formatted_address);
}
```

It works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an excellent candidate for cookies if you are allowed to use them: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.  Another idea is to pass it along in a Query String.  It isn't PII or anything like that.  Try an event code on that input.  I do not like to hit "enter"!

```
onkeypress="if (event.keycode==13) { // do something }"
```

Comment: I'm checking out the cookies, but I don't understand what to do with that afterwards. How to utilize it once the form is submitted.

Comment: So if you are setting a cookie value like so: `setCookie("client_address", document.getElementById("client_address").value, 30);`  You would get it like this: `var caddress=getCookie("client_address");`  Where 30 is the number of days it until that value would expire.  I typically use 720 which gives me 2 years.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do the opposite, make "client_address".value to be  what I get from autocomplete.GetPlace().formatted_address

Answer (score 0):

Handle the form submit event:

```
$(function() {
   $("#new_client").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // This is your value stored in the field.
      $("#client_address").val();
   });
})
```